# create label for graphics inside table cell and also add to table of contents

Tags: tables, graphics, table-of-contents, labels

I would like to create a few command that allows me to reference figures inside a table and add the reference to the table of contents.

```
\newcommand\fig[2]{
\addtocounter{figure}{1}
\includegraphics[width=3in]{#2}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Figure \ref{#1} #1}
\label{#1}
}
```

This is what I have tried, but the figure number does not seem to increment.

My goal is to generate something like in the screenshot below.  Thanks for your help!!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `capt-of` package (just one line of code) then you don't need `\refstepcounter` and `\addtocontents` simply do

```
... &
\includegraphics{fig}
\captionof{figure}{the caption}\label{myfig}
& ...
```

and the figure will be captioned and added to the list of figures in the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you're advancing the counter.  You need to be using `\refstepcounter` to get the label to refer to the correct figure number.

Incidentally, you are allowing a lot of extra white space into your command.   Try

```
\newcommand{\myfig}[2]
  {\refstepcounter{figure}%%'
   \includegraphics[width=2in]{#2}%%'
   \phantomsection
   \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Figure \ref{#1} #1}%%'
   \label{#1}%%'
  }
```

To get figures to be numbered within sections as you image seems to suggest you need to add two lines to your preamble.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
```

Comment: I think \csname phantomsection \endcsname is preferred.

Comment: @jesse I'm not sure I follow. `\csname phantomsection \endcsname` should do the same thing as `\phantomsection`; it's just a lot of typing.

Comment: indeed that is what I know of, but that produces an error while i follow your direction to try. Later on, i tried csname method and the error disappeared, thus the comment.

Comment: @Jesse Now I understand your point.  `\csname ....\endcsname` doesn't throw an error if the command name is not defined.  The OP did not list all of the packages needed for his example.  `\phantomsection` is a command defined in the `hyperref` package.  If you load that package, then you should be able cut and paste my example without error.

Comment: It is clear now. Thanks for the remark above.